# Handle a faulty expression

Tags: ios, cocoa, nspredicate

I'm checking an expression like this:

```
predicateExpression = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:jsonExpression];
```

But if the jsonExpression is faulty, I get an exception. Whats the best way to handle this? Currently there is a try/catch. Is there a way to do this with NSError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently there is a try/catch. Is there a way to do this with NSError?

You can add an extension to `NSPredicate` which duplicates an existing method and adds an `NSError **` argument. This is tricky, but not impossible, with variable argument methods, so let's use one of the variants of `predicateWithFormat:`

```
@interface NSPredicate (WithError)

+ (NSPredicate *) predicateWithFormat:(NSString *)format argumentArray:(nullable NSArray *)arguments error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

The implementation of this method just needs to call the underlying method `predicateWithFormat:argumentArray:` on `self` with a `try`/`catch`. In the `catch` clause if the passed `error` is not `nil` construct a suitable `NSError` value (you can include the original exception in the `userInfo` dictionary if you wish), assign it to `*error`, and return `nil` to indicate failure as well. If no exception occurs return the `NSPredicate` value.

You now a method with does not throw exceptions and returns an `NSError` value on error.

HTH